# configuration mangement on third party devices

Tags: configuration-management

Can anyone point me in the direction of configuration management software used for access and distribution level equipment? (i.e. DSLAM, GPON Equipment, Proprietary IP PBX Systems) These devices normally have telnet/ssh but have closed OS's. Thanks for any information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for systems that support exporting to human-readable configuration files or reports, i typically using some sort of version control that integrates a visual diff function. my current preference is TortoiseHg because it's easy enough to use by anyone in my IT department.